# How to get the userId parameter to call ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync

Tags: .net, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm developing a Chrome Extension which make calls to a .NET application. In that .NET application I work with the Gmail API to manage and read e-mails of the logged user.

I've followed the .NET API example that Google provides [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2/Default.aspx.cs?repo=samples&r=406dd0081ca556a81621b910eac4445e3309ad1e). In that example, there is a local variable declared like this:

```
    // Application logic should manage users authentication. 
    // This sample works with only one user. You can change
    // it by retrieving data from the session.
    private const string UserId = "user-id";
```

And there are plenty methods that use this variable as a parameter:

`var oauthState = AuthWebUtility.ExtracRedirectFromState(
                    flow.DataStore, UserId,...`

`var token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(UserId,...`

`var result = new AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, uri, uri).AuthorizeAsync(UserId,...`

My question is: how can I get the UserId? Should I get it from the session? Should I get it from somewhere in the chrome.storage?

Answer (score 1):

You can get user ID from the session. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) for the same.

```
public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
    {
             // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
           // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
        // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
        // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
        var user = controller.Session["user"];
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = Guid.NewGuid();
            controller.Session["user"] = user;
        }
        return user.ToString();

    }
```

However, the best practice is to use [Google+ sign in](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#choosing_a_sign-in_flow) for authentication. When a user is signed in, you get an OAuth token for making API requests on their behalf, which you can use to better understand your user. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sorry, I have to unmark the question as resolved. The `GetUserId`method doesn't work, because it gets a different user everytime. I will try with the Google+ method, but I have to make a lot of changes in my code.

Comment: Besides, the documentation is not very useful How can I set permissions to read and manage e-mails? How can I pass the token to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working on it recently.

Make sure you have include the correct scope in your very first redirect to Google:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

And then you only need to declare a string for it something like

```
private const string UserId = "user-id";
```

I'm not sure if this is a correct solution,
but it's working in my project

Just provided for you reference.

By the way, Have you solve the problem about connecting server with token yet?

Appreciate if you have some good advice for me, Thanks.

Comment: Using a unique user-id won't work with a multi-user application. About the token: I've concluded that the Google+ method only works with Javascript applications, not with server-side applications. Currently, I'm getting the user manually from the client and sending to the server by POST method.